# SQL Query - move decimal point

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, rounding

I have a table with one column where I need to format the values into a single form.

Results

```
1258
1248
1.18761801719666
1.1763299703598
1.21516096591949
```

Values like 1258 are correct. And I need values like 1.18761801719666 to get into similar forms (1188) with the last number being rounded.

When I used:

```
SELECT CAST(Results as DECIMAL(18,4)) as Results
FROM [Table]
```

So I get halfway to the desired result, but then I don't know.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
1258
1248
1.18761801719666
1.1763299703598
1.21516096591949
```

What I expect:

```
1258
1248
1187
1177
1215
```

Comment: Why format in SQL Server instead of your application? And please show both sample data and expected results.

Comment: So what would `11,8761` turn into? `118,7618`? `0,0124`? Is there no numerical significance to the separator?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sorry, my mistake. I used `,` separator instead of  `.` decimal separator. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.188` and `1188` are different numbers, not just different formats of the same number. So you need some actual mathematical operation here, not just formatting.

For instance, if the rules is "if the number is less than 10, multiply it by 1000", then you could write `CASE WHEN Results < 10 THEN Results * 1000 ELSE Results END`

You could then cast it to an integer to lose the rest of the decimal places:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN Results < 10 THEN Results * 1000 ELSE Results END as INT)
```